# JMeter and Oracle AQ

Tags: jmeter, oracle-aq

Anyone have any experience using JMeter and Oracle AQ? I'm trying to publish messages to the Oracle AQ queue using JMS Publisher but the only information I have is from a bindings file.

Answer (score 1):

First, read [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13738/aq_jms.htm) (*Oracle® Fusion Middleware Configuring and Managing JMS for Oracle WebLogic Server, Chapter 8: Interoperating with Oracle AQ JMS*), it provides you what you need to know about AQ user permission grants, AQ JMS Connection Factories names, and AQ Remote JNDI JMS Destination names. It does say WebLogic, but they use the very same config we do.

1. Put Oracle JDBC jar (ojdbc6.jar) and Oracle AQ jar (aqapi.jar, found in Weblogic's $WL_HOME/server/lib) in JMeter's lib dir.
2. Create a jndi.properties file with the following entries:

   ```
   java.naming.factory.initial=oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory
   db_url=Your Oracle DB instance JDBC URL
   java.naming.security.principal=username_with_aq_permission_grants
   java.naming.security.credentials=password
   ```
3. Put the jndi.properties into a jar with

   ```
   jar cf my-jndi-properties.jar jndi.properties
   ```

   and put it in that same JMeter lib dir.
4. Create a JMS Publisher in JMeter, and fill these:

   1. Check "Use jndi.properties file"
   2. Connection Factory: See [Table 8-1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13738/aq_jms.htm#JMSAD595) and put a AQ JMS Prefix Value. Don't use the generic factories.
   3. Destination: Either Queues/Your_Queue_Name or Topics/Your_Topic_Name
   4. Uncheck "Use Authorization?"

   Fill out what else you need.
5. Have fun.

Thanks [David L](http://anythingsimple.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/setup-jmeter-jms-publisher-sampler.html) for the jndi.properties info.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive instructions. I keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException` for `oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory` and when looking through the JARs I cannot seem to find it. I am using `aqapi13.jar`, however and don't have access to a Weblogic server.